# run protractor test without "webdriver-manager start"

Tags: typescript, webdriver, protractor, automated-tests

Can I run protractor test without writing manually in command line "webdriver-manager start" ? How can I run "webdriver-manager start" in code?
I write in TypeScript.

Comment: Assuming you&amp;#39;re using NPM, you could always add a a command that both starts webdriver and runs tests to the package.json scripts field, say -- "test": "webdriver-manager start && protractor prot.conf.js". Then you can run that defined command from terminal with "npm start test"

Comment: what should I change / write in my code?                                                      {
  "name": "protractorautomation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Protractor Typescript automation framework",
  "main": "config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "protractor": "^4.0.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "npm run tsc",
    "test": "protractor ConvertedJSFiles/config.js",
     "tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Protractor",
    "Typescript"
  ],
  "license": "ISC"
}

Comment: added an answer to more easily respond to you, @Jacob. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

*Expanding comments into answer*

**NPM Scripts with "&&"**

One idea is to use the NPM scripts block to essentially just make one command that you run that would both start your server and then your tests. You would just run this command and webdriver would start and then your tests would execute - you could then CTRL+C the server if you need to after your tests in the console window.

*Timing*

Webdriver-Manager might need a few moments to boot up the server. If the first script doesn't work for you try the second and notice the inclusion of "sleep()" to create a bootup delay for webdriver.

---

**(bootup > pretest > test) package.json**

```
{
  "name": "protractorautomation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Protractor Typescript automation framework",
  "main": "config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "protractor": "^4.0.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "npm run tsc",
    "test": "protractor ConvertedJSFiles/config.js",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "webdriver:start": "webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "dev": "npm run webdriver:start && npm run pretest && npm run test"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Protractor",
    "Typescript"
  ],
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**(bootup > sleep/delay > pretest > test) package.json**

```
{
  "name": "protractorautomation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Protractor Typescript automation framework",
  "main": "config.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "protractor": "^4.0.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sleep": "*"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "npm run tsc",
    "test": "protractor ConvertedJSFiles/config.js",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "sleep": "node sleep.js",
    "webdriver:start": "webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "dev": "npm run webdriver:start && npm run sleep && npm run pretest && npm run test"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Protractor",
    "Typescript"
  ],
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**sleep.js**

```
require('sleep').sleep([n seconds to sleep])
```

Comment: Where should be placed the require('sleep').sleep() ?

Answer (score 0):

You can defined gulp task instead. use npm install gulp & create a gulpfile.js

for more information refer my github repo: [github-repo-tyaga001](https://github.com/tyaga001/protractor-e2e-gulp-framework)

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpProtractor = require('gulp-angular-protractor');
var params = process.argv;
var args = process.argv.slice(3);
var paths = require('../paths.js');

// Execute e2e Tests
 gulp.task('e2e-test', function(callback) {
     gulp.src(paths.tests)
         .pipe((gulpProtractor({
                 configFile: 'protractor.conf.js',
                 args: args
         })).on('error', function(e) {
                 console.log(e);
             }).on('end', callback));
 });


 gulp.task('webdriver-update', gulpProtractor.webdriver_update);
gulp.task('webdriver-standalone', ['webdriver-update'], gulpProtractor.webdriver_standalone);
```